# Error in running any query on the phpmyadmin on the live server . But when i am runnign it on the adminer.php it is executing

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, server, phpmyadmin

I have a WordPress site on a Linux based server . The phpmyadmin is giving connectivity error . Daily it gives errors for different queries and today is giving me errors for any query which I am using .I used the same query yesterday and it helped me to fetch the data . But today it is not working . I also use the adminer.php and it is working fine and giving the data based on the query . Can anyone tell me I will give a screenshot of the error . Please give your thought on it .
[image: Screenshot of the error]
Here is the query which I am running .

```
SELECT u.id,f.meta_value as first_name,l.meta_value as last_name,u.user_nicename as slug,u.user_email as email,u.user_pass as password,b.meta_value as badge_id,e.meta_value as expiry_date,lc.meta_value as location_id, u.emailVarification as verification_code,v.meta_value as user_verified,s.meta_value as remember_token,u.user_registered as created_at,p.post_modified as updated_at,d.meta_value as is_disabled
FROM `wp_users` as  u
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta as f ON f.user_id = u.ID AND f.meta_key = "first_name"
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta as l ON l.user_id = u.ID AND l.meta_key = "last_name"
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta as b ON b.user_id = u.ID AND b.meta_key = "badge_id"
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta as e ON e.user_id = u.ID AND e.meta_key = "expiry_date"
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta as lc ON lc.user_id = u.ID AND lc.meta_key = "location_id"
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta as v ON v.user_id = u.ID AND v.meta_key = "_is_verified"
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta as s ON s.user_id = u.ID AND s.meta_key = "session_tokens"
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta as d ON d.user_id = u.ID AND d.meta_key = "is_disabled"


LEFT JOIN wp_posts as p ON p.post_author=u.id
WHERE p.post_type="freelancers"
AND u.freelancerpaid="1"
```

Comment: This may be an issue with the server. Have you checked server health?

Comment: How do I check the health of the server

Comment: The server admin should be able to do that. If you are. the server admin, you should google that question.

Comment: Any hints in the webserver error log? A 520 error code suggests you're running behind the Cloudflare service, if you temporarily bypass the service does the problem still occur?

Comment: The issue was because of the cloudfare and i bypassed it and it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because of the Cloudfare installed on the server I tried to bypass it and everything worked . Thanks everyone for the answers .